# Align element in div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains two divs inside. First div has to be aligned to the left , second div has to be 
aligned to the center relatively parent div.Please could you help me .Here is my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/armakarma/zy3L9a7h/

[image]

html

```
<div class='test'>
  <div class='logo'>logo</div>
  <div class='title'> title </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.test{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.title{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo{
  width:160px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: unable to understand your issue. !

Comment: @PraveenMurali title has to be aligned relatively parent div